# How to update one or two series from multiple series on JQuery Flot

Tags: flot

It's my first time using JQuery Flot for my project and I got a problem with multiple series.

```
var data5 = [[0,10],[1,20],..];
var data6 = [[0,5],[1,25],..];

var series = [{data:data1},{data:data2},{data:data3},{data:data4},{label:"DATA A",data:data5},{label:"DATA B",data:data6}];
```

series 1-4 are template lines and 5 & 6 are the real lines where data can be changed anytime..

how to update series 5 & 6 without editing other series?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to update series 5 & 6 without editing other series?

The short answer is you don't.  You redraw all the series.  At first, this may seem like a limitation of flot, but it draws so incredibly fast, refreshing the entire chart doesn't matter.

```
    // get current data from chart
    var someData = plot.getData();
    // take the second series and push on a new point
    someData[1].data.push([someData[1].data.length,Math.random() * 10]);
    // set the data back to the charts
    plot.setData(someData);
    // recalculate the axis
    plot.setupGrid();
    // redraw the plot
    plot.draw();
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mR46n/), which updates a chart every 100 ms.